# TLS setup on K8S Ingress with Traefik

Tags: ssl, https, kubernetes, traefik

I have a setup that is not too much different than the [user guide](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kubernetes/) for use with k8s. For some reason I can only access `http://app.minikube` and not `https://app.minikube`.

Can someone look at my setup and see what I am obviously missing?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: myapp
 labels:
   app: myapp
spec:
 ports:
 - name: http
   port: 80
   targetPort: 7777
 selector:
   app: myapp
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 name: myingress
 annotations:
   kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
spec:
 rules:
 - host: app.minikube
   http:
     paths:
     - path: /
       backend:
         serviceName: myapp
         servicePort: http
 tls:
  - secretName: mytls
```

FYI, according to the [Traefik user guide](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kubernetes/#add-a-tls-certificate-to-the-ingress), the `hosts` definition in `tls` is unneeded, which is why I left it out.

> The field hosts in the TLS configuration is ignored. Instead, the domains provided by the certificate are used for this purpose. It is recommended to not use wildcard certificates as they will match globally)

Comment: how are you creating the secret? what errors do you get?

Comment: I think the secret is fine: `kubectl create secret tls mytls --key=tls.key --cert=tls.crt`. The error is just a Not Found.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `hosts` section:

```
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - my-host.example.com
    secretName: my-secret
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the thought. But, the documentation specifically says that this is not needed: "The field hosts in the TLS configuration is ignored. Instead, the domains provided by the certificate are used for this purpose. It is recommended to not use wildcard certificates as they will match globally."

Comment: Oh well... mine is working,  and the hosts is the only difference I can spot, perhaps  it's not able to read the secret or something like this. good luck on solving this, and  add an answer/update when you do :)